# Message thread with mute icon (speaker w slash through)

Tags: sms, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-6

My message thread to my GF has a mute icon (speaker w slash through) and it doesnt alert me when she messages, how do i get rid of that? Phone just recently updated to marshmallow > Galaxy S6

Answer (score 2):

There's a drop down box for her number when you're inside the thread. If you hit that and then tap on notification settings you can turn notifications for her sms back on.